# is there a "run as" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, runas

I have issue with user without local admin who want to install font on their PC call me everyday. The thing is there is no run as, like in windows XP.I don't want to logoff user session and go into local admin account to install font, their would losing productivity and losing my time to do it.

Comment: What makes you think that logging off is anywhere required for logging on as an administrator?

Answer (score 8):

You can either right click on an application and 'Run As Administrator' giving the admin credentials or if you hold down the Shift key and right click you can 'Run As A Different User' and enter the credentials of a user with admin rights.

You can also set the item to be "Run as Administrator" permanently for a single user account or for all users based on the picture link below.

Right Click -> Properties
Select the "Compatibility" tab and select "Run as Administrator"
Click "Change settings for all users" to apply settings for all users who run the specific item.

Click [image: Example]

And if neither of those works, give the following a go, it's a bit convuluted bit it will work: http://tompopov.blogspot.com/2011/05/allowing-non-admin-users-to-install.html

Comment: it only work for executable file, but not font file. >_<

Comment: That manual font install is probably too complex for a standard user to do.  I think the best solution is probably to create a shim app that can be elevated to install the fonts.

Comment: Perhaps SuRun might help then? http://sourceforge.net/projects/surun/

Answer (score 2):

For installing fonts, try this from a command prompt (or possibly the run box):

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\User "control fonts"
```